# Passing Type parameter dynamically

Tags: c#, type-parameter

I'm getting a list of classes in my Assembly like this:

`Type[] theseTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();`

and need to pass them to a method that looks like this:

`o = RandomValue.Object<Lce.State.Store.Models.Events.OrderPaymentEvent>();`

However I can't figure out how to call the .Object method with a type from the theseTypes array.

TIA!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)